# Loading Array of images horizontally in recyclerview using Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview, horizontal-scrolling

I have a recyclerview.I am trying to load images horizontally int o it but i keeping getting the foll error

```
You must provide a Model of a type for which there is a registered ModelLoader, if you are using a custom model, you must first call Glide#register with a ModelLoaderFactory for your custom model class
```

I tried searching a lot but couldn't get an answer that would help me.Following is my code

```
public class Images {

    public String[] imageUrl;



    public String[] getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String[] imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Images(String[] imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }
}


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Images> imagesList;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView recyclerimageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            recyclerimageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerlistitemimageview);
        }


    }
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<Images> imagesList){
        this.context=context;
        this.imagesList=imagesList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recyclerlistitem, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      //  Glide.with(context).load(myarr).into(holder.recyclerimageView);
        Images images=imagesList.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(images.getImageUrl()).into(holder.recyclerimageView);
         }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
       // return myarr.length;
    }
}


public class Arrayclass {
public static String activa3gimage3[]={"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/venetian-honda-179411.appspot.....",
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.......",
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis....",
    "https://firebasestorage.googleapis......"};

}
```

I have uploaded my image to server and taking the uri of images in activa3gimage3 array

```
    public class ModelLineUpInnerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     private List<Images> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerAdapter mAdapter;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_model_line_up_inner);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
Images images=new Images(Arrayclass.activa3gimage3);
                imagesList.add(images);
mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(ModelLineUpInnerActivity.this,imagesList);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
    }
```

I know that the error is beacause of Glide and i am trying to load array of images into it,but don't know how to resolve it.Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use single url to download and load image into single image using array with index so use

```
 Glide.with(context).load(images.getImageUrl()[position]).into(holder.recyclerimageView);
 //                                           ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Update :

Your list is containing only single item so you need to modify list with all the items in it

```
Images images=new Images(Arrayclass.activa3gimage3);
imagesList.add(images); //  single item so single view
```

---

Use `List<String>` and eliminate use of `Images` because your adapter only needs String `url` to load images.

```
public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> imagesList;
    // use String list 

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context,List<String> imagesList){
        this.context=context;
        this.imagesList=imagesList;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
          Glide.with(context).load(imagesList.get(position)).into(holder.recyclerimageView);
         }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return imagesList.size();
    }

 // ... code
```

and setup adapter like

```
 private List<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_model_line_up_inner);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);

        imagesList.addAll(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Arrayclass.activa3gimage3)));
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(ModelLineUpInnerActivity.this,imagesList);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Then it would load only the first image.I want it to load all the images of the array

Comment: Is it possible to load multiple images in single imageview using glide or picasso?

Comment: yeah i am on it, i have seen that issue , updating the answer , in short you need to use  all items instead of single image in list

Comment: do you really want to use `Image` class because it can be eliminated by using array with `recyclerView`

Comment: Not necessary to use image class if it can solve the problem

Comment: I can't use get method in onBindViewHolder if i am using array instead of list

Comment: you don't need to , that line was left by mistake so remove it , code updated

Comment: Still getting the first image

Comment: you mean there is only single item or all item are with same image

Comment: i am glad that i could help ,i gonna update my code with `List` because list can be manipulated dynamically (add,remove) so u can use that later for more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

`images.getImageUrl()` is array, and you need a `String` with url of your image

Use `List<String>` instead of `List<Images>` (also update it in your `RecyclerAdapter` & `ModelLineUpInnerActivity`)

```
private List<String> imagesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add your urls in this list, like this:

```
imagesList.addAll(Arrays.asList(Arrayclass.activa3gimage3));
```

After that you can load your image:

```
String image = imagesList.get(position);
Glide.with(context).load(image).into(holder.recyclerimageView);
```

Comment: But i want to load array of images

Comment: how to load array of images,any idea?

Comment: Updated answer @Cycle

Comment: It only loads the first image of the array

Comment: Have you updated your RecyclerAdapter? Can you show your updated code? @Cycle

Comment: yes i have updated everything as you said,but it loads only the first image

Comment: Are you sure that your activa3gimage3 contains correct images? @Cycle